# consulta en php usuarios registrados

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

No sé si este bien esta consulta, quiero saber el número de usuarios registrados en mi base de datos.

```
$regist = ejecutarSQL::consultar("select count(*) total from cliente");
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regist);
echo '<p>Número de total de registros: '.$fila['total'].'</p>';
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas el Editor de SQL, haces esa misma consulta y verificas el resultado?

Comment: En principio está bien, pero ¿Por qué no la has probado? ¿Cúal es el error?

Comment: no me muestra el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría más fácil, metería un id en la tabla cliente, haría un select de los id, metería el resultado en un array y luego es solo recorrerlo.